# HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 - Cant Access Raid Controller

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid, raid5

i have a HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 Server with ah P420 Raid Controller. I have configured Raid 5 with 3 Disks. I want to expand the Raid with 2 more Disks. But i cannot access the Raid Controller -> HP Smart Storage Administrator anymore. On Bootup screen it says press F5. When i press F5 it recognize it but it stucks for 10 seconds and then boots to Ubuntu.

Does anyone have an idea why i cannot access it anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Download [HPE Smart Storage Administrator](https://buy.hpe.com/us/en/software/server-management-software/server-management-software/smart-array-management-software/hpe-smart-storage-administrator/p/5409020), burn it on CD/USB and boot from this media. And you will be able to manage RAID array on the server.

Comment: i will try that thank you

Comment: doesnt work. is it compatible with gen8? i only find gen9 and gen10

Comment: @t_mod2k, not sure. So you should search for old storage disk

Comment: isnt there any other fixes? i wouldnt like to boot every time from the usb stick when i wanna access the raid configuration. it worked fine 2 days ago :D